# Deploying a custom health rule fails on Add Solution

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, deployment, health-analyzer

I've created a custom health rule for checking which mode solutions were built in (following [this guide](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Custom-Health-Rule-for-SharePoint-2010-that-checks-for-Debug-build-assemblies.aspx)) but am having trouble deploying it. When deploying from VS2010, I get

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Health analyzer rule registration
requires that the {0} assembly be registered in the global assembly cache.
```

I've tried using management shell to deploy it, but it silently fails when I try to activate it, which uninstalls it.

Does anyone have any experience of health rules? There's very little on Google about this error. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check if the assembly is in the WSP (rename to CAB and check)?

Comment: Yes, it's there, and set to deploy to GAC.

Comment: Did you create this as a Farm Solution and not a Sandboxed Solution?

Comment: It's a farm solution.

Answer (score 1):

please make sure your following this:

**How to: Create a Feature to Register a Health Rule**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee538252(v=office.14).aspx

sounds like you got through that part fine! but the part that its failing on i think is the gac registering! its looking in the file but cant find it as its looking in another location! so follow this aswell to make sure that your app is looking in the gac and nowhere else:

**How to: Deploy a Health Rule with a Solution Package**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee537821(v=office.14).aspx

taken from the above link:

```
<Solution SolutionId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <FeatureManifests>
    <FeatureManifest Location="FeatureFolderName\feature.xml" />
  </FeatureManifests>
  <Assemblies>
    <Assembly DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache"
              Location="AssemblyName.dll" />
  </Assemblies>
</Solution>
```